# Change Button Color on state change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

[image]

I want for the buttons to have white background and blue title when highlighted. I have an extension of UIButton to set its background color.

```
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

}
```

and in the next function, I set up a particular button.

```
private func stylizingButton(button: UIButton){
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2
        button.layer.borderColor = textColor.cgColor
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        button.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)

        button.setTitleColor(backgroundColor, for: .highlighted)
        button.setBackgroundColor(color: .white, forState: .highlighted)

    }
```

When I change the background color of the button to black, the result is some dark blue color. It is like the screen background color and the button's color are mixing.

Comment: do you use `setBackgroundColor` for setting it to black, too?

Comment: yes, and then I get dark blue color when it is highlighted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom class for your button and handle your color changing properties on state like below.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    fileprivate var titleColorNormal: UIColor = .white
    fileprivate var titleColorHighlighted: UIColor = .blue
    fileprivate var backgroundColorNormal: UIColor = .blue
    fileprivate var backgroundColorHighlighted: UIColor = .white
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        willSet(newValue){
            if newValue {
                self.setTitleColor(titleColorHighlighted, for: state)
                self.backgroundColor = backgroundColorHighlighted
            }else {
                self.setTitleColor(titleColorNormal, for: state)
                self.backgroundColor = backgroundColorNormal
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks :] You just need to override the normal state and it will work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Either make image for the whole size, or make it stretchable, so it can fill the whole background:

```
extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, for state: UIControlState) {

        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        let stretchable = image!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: insets, resizingMode: .tile)
        self.setBackgroundImage(stretchable, for: state)
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I copy/paste it and the result is the same

Comment: @Rango show the rest of the relevant code in your code base

Comment: I used **view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor** for the screen background color and this method **stylizingButton(:UIButton)** is called from a **viewDidLoad** and as an argument is passed a button outlet. There is just this function in extension

Comment: @Rango well, I use this code and it works perfectly in my code base.. therefore I can only assume that you are doing something either in storyboards or in the rest of the code that you did not share, which ends in this side effect

Comment: Thanks for your trouble :]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the mixing colors in highlighted state but didn't want to create a custom class. I found out that you can simply change the button type from "System" to "Custom". Then you can use the functions for setting colors by state. The colors will be displayed as defined.

[You can change the button type in interface builder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enI38.png)